# CsvLink in react app calling as event from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export-to-csv

Im using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv component for CSV export. It works fine, but now, I need to call export function from onClick of another component which can not contain this component itself.

Is there any way to trigger on click download csv button behavior though the code?

For example:

```
function handlePolicy(action) {
    switch (action) {
        case 'export':
            //Export CSV 

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
 //this is onClick from some specific ActionMenu component which takes as argument only string as //an option choice.
```

Also I tried CSVDownload, but it doesnt trigger onLoad page, or on click of a button